# Terraform destroy azure load balancer

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-vm-scale-set

I've been trying to create an Azure virtual machine scale set with terraform and it's creating it fine, but when I try to perform Terraform `destroy`, I receive this message below. Any ideas on how I could solve this issue?

```
Error: Error waiting for completion of Load Balancer "vmss-see-d-01-LB" (Resource Group "RG-VMSS-D-SEE-01"):
    Code="Canceled"
    Message="Operation was canceled."
    Details=[{
        "code":"CanceledAndSupersededDueToAnotherOperation",
        "message":"Operation PutLoadBalancerOperation (81ab2118-37e3-4552-a2f7-e1e12bccb1e5) was canceled and superseded by operation InternalOperation (1d4e2e27-f457-4941-b3b8-e6352f84ddd1)."
    }]
```

Comment: Can you share your Terraform code? It's more helpful.

Comment: Hi Charles thanks for your support its seams was something related with the azurerm_lb_nat_rule, once i removed it everything went fine.

Comment: That's the problem, so I ask for the code. I will add an answer to display the exact reason, hope you accept it.

Comment: Can that answer help you understand the problem?

Comment: yes i got your answer,thanks for that ! but i still have issues to understand properly  how dependencies works in terraform

Comment: Take a look at the Terraform [depends_on](https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/getting-started/dependencies.html).

Comment: im gonna do that, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error shows, you must put the virtual machine scale set behind a Load Balancer. While the VMSS was in the backend pool of the load balancer, and you also create a nat rule or load balancer for it, then there are dependencies between the VMSS and the Load Balancer: the Load Balancer depends on the VMSS. So if you want to delete the VMSS directly, then the error comes.

So the right sequence to delete the VMSS is that delete the nat rule or the load balancer rule associated with the VMSS, then remove the VMSS from the backend pool of the load balancer. When all the above steps are finished. The last step is deleting the VMSS.

Hope it can help you understand why does the error happen to you.